# How to cheaply merge char arrays and numbers together?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a couple of arrays and numbers like this:

```
char *test = "bla";
char *test1 = "bla bla";
float test2 = 3.14;
int test3 = 556878;
```

I would like to merge them all, in that order, into a single char array, but I cannot use something like `snprintf`, because this code runs on Arduino, where memory is at a premium.

Expected result:

```
char *merged = "blabla bla3.14556878";
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: You want to have array like this `"blabla bla3.14556878"`?

Comment: Yes, it want to merge them into a single char array.

Comment: Have you seen this "https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/26875/arduino-how-do-i-convert-a-float-into-char"?

Comment: **Pointers are not arrays** and **arrays are not pointers**. I suggest you read section 6 of the [c-faq](https://c-faq.com/). *The code you post has absolutely no array you can write to.*

Answer (score 1):

Use `itoa()` and `ftoa()` to convert `int` and `float` values to stings, then use `strcat`.

`itoa` will work in **arduino.**

The `ftoa` function is provided below:

```
char buff1[10];
char buff2[10];

itoa(test3,buff1,10);
ftoa(test2,buff2,3);

void ftoa(float n, char *res, int afterpoint) 
{ 
    // Extract integer part 
    int ipart = (int)n; 

    // Extract floating part 
    float fpart = n - (float)ipart; 

    // convert integer part to string 
    itoa(ipart, res, 10); 

    int i = strlen(res);

    // check for display option after point 
    if (afterpoint != 0) 
    { 
        res[i] = '.';  // add dot 

        // Get the value of fraction part upto given no. 
        // of points after dot. The third parameter is needed 
        // to handle cases like 233.007 
        fpart = fpart * pow(10, afterpoint); 

        itoa((int)fpart, res + i + 1, 10); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Whilst professing along this line, remember *neither* of those are standard-defined library functions.